# Predefined string segfaults when copied to by strncpy()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, strncpy

Why is it that ...

```
char *dst = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 11);
char *src = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ";
strncpy(dst, src, 10);
```

... works fine, but ...

```
char *dst = "ABCDEFGHIJ\0";
char *src = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ\0";
strncpy(dst, src, 10);
```

... or even ...

```
char *dst = "ABCDEFGHIJ\0";
char *src = "KLMNOPQRST\0";
strncpy(dst, src, 10);
```

gives *segfault*?

Also, how come this works:

```
char *dst = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10); // also works with 9
char *src = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ\0";
strncpy(dst, src, 10);
```

Copying 11 bytes into a pointer allocated with 10 bytes should in principle fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the string literals you initialized to the pointers **dst** and **src**  in the later cases are stored in the data segment. A data segment is a portion of virtual address space of a program, which contains the global variables and static variables that are initialized by the programmer.

This segment can be further classified into initialized read-only area and initialized read-write area.

For instance the global string defined by

```
char s[] = “hello world”
```

in C and a C statement like int debug=1 outside the main (i.e. global) would be stored in initialized read-write area. And a global C statement like

```
const char* string = “hello world”
```

makes the string literal “hello world” to be stored in initialized read-only area and the character pointer variable string in initialized read-write area.

And in the above case...

```
char* dst = " ABCD........." ;
```

is equivalent to

```
const temp[]="ABCD......";

char* dst = &temp[0];
```

so the temp array which the dst is pointing will be stored in readonly memory and hence you cannot edit it...

Also in the final case even though you can copy 11 bytes into a pointer pointing to 10 bytes, you will encounter troubles during run time.... For eg: try freeing the pointer and you will face segmentation fault...( Undefined behaviour).

It is compiler dependent.

Comment: Appreciate the thorough explanation! Is it then, however, safe to do this?

 char *s = "hey";
 printf("%s %p\n", s, &s);
 
 s = "you there";
 printf("%s %p\n", s, &s);

It points to the same address after being reassigned:

hey 0x7fffb4a809e8
you there 0x7fffb4a809e8

(not that it's the same thing, I am just curious)

Comment: Yes it is safe to do it.. Coz you are not changing the string literal "hey"... Instead you are just creating a new string " you there" in the memory and asking the pointer s to point to it...  Also &s is the address of variable s, not the address of the string literal it is pointing to...

Answer (score 6):

String literals may be stored in a read-only memory segment. You are not supposed to modify them.

Also, there's no checking for writing beyond bounds. Many of the security problems you hear of stem from the fact that there's a lot of code without any bounds checking.

Writing beyond the bounds of allocated memory, as well as attempting to modify a string literal or other read-only/constant data, leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).